# Using PayPal webhooks with NVP DoExpressCheckoutPayment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp, paypal-webhooks

I'm working on a website where a user can pay for products to another user, the user that is getting paid has his `API Signature` set and the payment is accomplished using `ExpressCheckout (NVP)` (the payer just gets redirected to a PayPal page where he logs in if necessary and just clicks a button to pay).

The problem is I tried using webhooks to track refunds for these payments, so I can later insert the refund data into my database via callback URL (php function), but the URL I've set doesn't get called at all(I've previously simulated an event on the same URL and everything was fine).

I am trying to get this to work by setting my `API Signature` and a friend of mine paying me some cents(via `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`) after which I refund them to him (no calls, only using the PayPal website).

Also nothing appears on the Sandbox Webhooks Events page or the Live one. I've tried registering other events like "Payment capture completed" or "Payment sale completed" to my webhook but with the same result.

Do I have to change some settings in my account? I've created a REST API app in order to use webhooks, but I've seen there's an option for NVP/SOAP API apps. I have considered IPN if webhooks don't work.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: I can show you the first lines, before any validation:
`$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($body);`
I insert `json_encode($post)` to my database, it worked for the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Webhooks" are used with the REST API.  Express Checkout uses [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

You'll need to setup a separate listener for IPN similar to what you've done with webhooks on the REST API.